# Bayesian least absolute deviations

Tags: regression, bayesian, linear-model, least-absolute-deviations

Ordinary Least Squares have a bayesian equivalent. For instance, fitting the linear model
$$ y \sim a + bx + \epsilon $$
using OLS is equivalent to defining the following Bayesian linear model:
$$ y \sim N(a + bx, \sigma) $$
$$ a \sim N(0, 1) $$
$$ b \sim N(0, 1) $$
$$ \sigma \sim exp(1) $$

(this is more or less equivalent, as the Bayesian model adds regularization via the prior, and it is actually equivalent to fitting a ridge regression).

Is there an equivalent Bayesian model to the least absolute deviation fit?

---

Please note that ordinary least squares implies solving:
$$\min_{a, b} |y - a - bx|^2 $$
while least absolute deviations solve:
$$\min_{a, b} |y - a - bx| $$

Comment: Besides using a double-exponential for the noise distribution?

Comment: I'm not following, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/016214508000000337

Comment: This is different, one thing is doing a Lasso (lasso minimizes least squares will adding L1 penalties on the parameters), and the other, which I am asking, is minimizing the L1 distance to the target. I'll clarify it on the question

Comment: What @Xi'an means is that with a double exponential (Laplacian) response, the maximum likelihood estimator minimizes least absolute deviations.  So, just use that model, adopt some prior prior, and run the Bayesian machine.